# Best way to clear cache / reload site when theming css

Tags: 7, theming

I have a huge drupal 7 project.

When I make changes on my css-files and reload the site in the browser (I work locally), the changes do not appear.

I have to clear the cache (theme caching is deactivated in drupal), have to reload the site many time, have to laod .../style.css file in Browser to check if the changes appear in css file ...).

But loading and re-loading the site the changes do not appear. 
Mybe browser cache is the problem?

What is the best way to to these theming and test after some css changes in browser? (It is a huge projects, loading and clearing cache etc. lasts very very long, so all these things take a lot of time).

How to work timesaving? Thank you.

Comment: If you hold shift while clicking refresh, it will bypass the browser cache and pull everything directly from the server.

Comment: Is this the same as CTRL + R or what is the difference?

Comment: On a mac, it's the same as command+shift+r. I don't know about windows.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use Drush for that. Commands are very easy and helps a lot specially with caching.There are other useful features of it.

[Drush Git Hubm URL](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush)

Specifically, once you have Drush installed. Use 'drush cc' (cache-clear).

Comment: Of course I am using drush! But the problem is: clearing the cache last 3-8 minutes. I can not way 5 minutes after any simple css change I want to test.